# WOO-Commerce translation | Tried it all

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, translation

Hope anyone can help me with this problem.
I installed WOO-Commerce all great and I set up the language to Dutch ...

But as you can see there are still a lot of small things still not adjusted to Dutch. http://www.vonvuurenblusbal.nl/

Also I tried multibol plugins like the Loco Translate,
WooCommerce (nl) etc ... but all does not seem to work.

Is there anyone that has any idea?
Please let me know.

Comment: Pleas let me know how this can not be a Wordpress qwestion?
... ???

Answer (score 1):

Your website looks working properly.

[image: http://www.vonvuurenblusbal.nl/]

If still, there are some strings not translating then you need to add appropriate Dutch strings for missing strings.

For that you can use tool [poedit](https://poedit.net/).

Further reference: [Translating with poedit](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/poedit/)

Comment: Thank you I tried that but there is in some way an over richt from some where wich I can not seem to find out.

Comment: Have you changed the language of your website from _Dashboard->Settings->General->Site Language_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [POEDIT](https://poedit.net/) to edit the translations of woocommerce. Find Languages folder in the plugin files and open the `.po` file that you need to edit. You'll see all the translations and even ones missing.

Here's a tutorial from woocommerce: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/ and information about contributing to their translations.

If there are things missing in the code, your best bet is to search woocommerce for the word that's in english and double check they're wrapped with a textdomain, they should look something like this: `__( 'example', 'woocommerce' );`

IF you find the words aren't wrapped, you can file [issues with woocommerce](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues) on github to let them know.

Comment: Thank you I tried that but there is in some way an over richt from some where wich I can not seem to find out.